# Python os.path.expandvars only works for some variables

Tags: python, environment-variables

Running `os.path.expandvars` fails for some env variables. Seems too basic to be real.

```
$ echo $HOSTTYPE 
x86_64
$ echo $HOME     
/labhome/eladw
$ python -c 'import os; print os.path.expandvars("$HOSTTYPE")'
$HOSTTYPE
$ python -c 'import os; print os.path.expandvars("$HOME")'
/labhome/eladw
```

Any idea what I'm missing (I am running python 2.7)?

Comment: Is `HOSTTYPE` exported to subprocesses?

Comment: there's a difference between `export HOME=` and `HOSTTYPE=`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728731/how-to-access-shell-variable-in-ipython, or rather a duplicate

Answer (score 6):

Environment variables set in a shell are not automatically *exported* to subprocesses. Just because your *shell* has a `HOSTTYPE` variable, doesn't mean this is variable is visible to subprocesses.

Export the variable first:

```
$ export HOSTTYPE
```

You can combine setting and exporting a variable in one step with:

```
$ export HOSTTYPE=x86_64
```

Demo:

```
$ HOSTTYPE=x86_64
$ python -c 'import os; print os.path.expandvars("$HOSTTYPE")'
$HOSTTYPE
$ export HOSTTYPE
$ python -c 'import os; print os.path.expandvars("$HOSTTYPE")'
x86_64
```

See [*Difference between environment variables and exported environment variables in bash*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/difference-between-environment-variables-and-exported-environment-variables-in-b).